# Rewrite all requests, excepts one folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to htaccess, but I wanted to rewrite all urls coming to my webserver to index.php?params=$1, except the assets folder. I've tried something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^assets($|/) index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

But, when I use var_dump for the params variable, it returns an empty variable.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets/|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```